# not able to open jmc for java version jdk1.8.0_191.jdk

Tags: java, jprofiler, jmc

I have a mac system. Whenever i try to open java JMC, it doesn't open. I can just see maximise, minimise and close buttons for the dialog box. The jdk version im using is jdk1.8.0_191.jdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately a bug that we recently discovered, caused by incompatibilities between old Eclipse/SWT versions and new fixes done in `JDK 8u152 (backported from JDK 9)`.

Workaround is to run older version of JDK 8, or the latest version of JDK 7 (which includes the same version of JMC). JDK 9 also works, with the new JMC 6 included.

(Oracle Internal) `bug reference: JMC-5139`

or

There's a workaround for this, as mentioned by `@jwatkins` in a comment.

```
Download the swt cocoa jar from here.
Go to JDKs jmc path (You can find this path by right-clicking on jmc icon in the dock -> Options -> Show in Finder, Then right click on App -> Show Package Contents).

For example:  cd
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol
Back up exisiting jar using sudo mv
plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.103.1.v20140903-1947.jar
../

Copy downloaded zip's swt.jar using sudo cp ~/Downloads/swt.jar
plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.103.1.v20140903-1947.jar
Restart jmc
```

it works for `1.8.0_171`

Comment: hi could you pls provide a proper link to the swt jar?